# Julia: How do I copy a DataFrame to the system clipboard?

Tags: julia

In Julia, I would like to be able to copy a DataFrame (from the DataFrames.jl package) to the system clipboard in a format that allows me to easily paste it into another program like Excel.

If I just try `clipboard(df)` then it just gives me the output as if I ran `print(df)` at the console, which doesn't paste cleanly into Excel.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `sprint()` and `show()` functions in combination around the DataFrame first, as below:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(rand(2, 3));
clipboard(sprint(show, "text/tab-separated-values", df))
```

Since you're asking about Excel in particular, the "text/tab-separated-values" MIME type will structure the output such that it will paste cleanly into Excel cells. You could also specify other types, such as comma-separated:

```
clipboard(sprint(show, "text/csv", df))
```

Check out the documentation on `sprint()` and `show()` for more details on how this works, it's quite flexible for other use cases as well.

Comment: To clarify, `sprint(f, args...)` takes whatever would be printed by `f(args...)` and returns it as a string?